# How to use auth0s refresh token when using webauth.authorize()

Tags: auth0

I am using the Auth0 webauth.authorize() pop up to log in to my react native app.
I receive the refreshToken back after log in but how do I use this refresh token to get a new access token? Is it possible with webauth or do I need to use the sdk?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are already using the SDK if you are using `webauth.authorize()`. Using the [react-native-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0) package, you can use the following code to exchange a refresh token for an access token:

```
auth0.auth
  .refreshToken({refreshToken: 'the user refresh_token'})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```